# Php unusual fatal error with "name is already in use"

Tags: php, namespaces

On my local development machine (php 5.3.14) I can use a class like this:

```
<?php

namespace Shop\Repository;

use Shop\Entity\Day;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class Product extends EntityRepository
{
    // Code
}
```

The class is stored in /my/src/Shop/Repository/Product.php (PSR-0 compliant). I have **also** a `Shop\Repository\Day` located at /my/src/Shop/Repository/Day.php.

However, on my staging server (php 5.3.10) I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use Shop\Entity\Day as Day because the name is already in use in /my/src/Shop/Repository/Product.php on line 5

I can understand the message, if I alias my Shop\Entity\Day import to DayEntity, the code works. But I cannot understand the cause of the fatal error: why does this work on php 5.3.14 (or at least, with my configuration) and not with 5.3.10 (or at least, with the server's configuration)?

I guess the problem is because in the namespace `Shop\Repository` there is already a `Day` loaded. But this has never lead to errors in my setup! What's going on?

Comment: `use Shop\Entity\Day as EntityDay;`, or just refer to it with it's fully qualified name and get rid of the `use` declaration completely. Maybe re-read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) as well.

Comment: It's obvious you will get a collision if you import a class called Day into a namespace that already has a class called Day. As to why it works on your local set-up; I can't see any bugfixes in the changelog related to namespaces between 5.4.10 and 5.3.14. Is it possible that locally your Repository\Day class hasn't been used at the point you load Entity\Day ?

Comment: @Leigh I am requesting the exact same page, with the exact same clones from git. This must be a (php) configuration issue therefore.

Comment: @DaveRandom I guess you are right. I understand namespaces pretty well, but because this was working on my local machine I never figured out this could be a problem inside a file where the namespace declaration is at the top like the one I provided here.

Comment: @JurianSluiman It's all about what has been loaded. If the file containing the `Shop\Repository\Day` class has been loaded (`include`d), the name `Day` is already in use in the current namespace. If it has not been loaded, the name is not in use and your code would succeed - but if you then tried to include `Shop\Repository\Day` then you would get the same error. In general if you have two classes with the same name from different namespaces, and you need to refer to both of them in the same place, use the fully qualified name to avoid confusion. You can alias as above, but I don't like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some explanation I grabbed about this situation:

```
require_once 'ns_class2.php';
// 
namespace ns; // Declaration of the namespace named "ns"
class class2 {} // Declaration of the class "ns/class2"
// In the namespace "ns", "class2" is an alias of  "ns\class2"
// 


require_once 'ns_ns1_ns2_class2.php';
// 
namespace ns\ns1\ns2; // Declaration of the namespace named "ns\ns1\ns2"
class class2 {} // Declaration of the class "ns\ns1\ns2\class2"
// In the namespace "ns\ns1\ns2", "class2" is an alias of "ns\ns1\ns2\class2"
//  

require_once 'ns_ns1_ns2_class1.php';
// 
namespace ns\ns1\ns2; // Declaration of the namespace named "ns\ns1\ns2"
// In the namespace "ns\ns1\ns2", "class2" is an alias of "ns\ns1\ns2\class2"
use ns\class2; // Creation of the alias  "class2" which point to "ns\class2" but class2 is already an alias of ns\ns1\ns2\class2 => ERROR
```

So you should try with get_included_files() to see on your server and station what are the differents because the order to load them is important

Those explanation are linked from [this nice post](http://blog.mageekbox.net/?post/2011/07/14/Espace-de-noms-et-importations-de-classes) which was commented by [dmitry](http://php100.wordpress.com/)

Hope this could help